# Auto updater not working

Tags: java

So I am trying to make an auto updater to the game that I'm making in java, but it doesn't work. With a lot of debugging I have found out that it is the part when it tries to start the game it stops. It promts nothing whats so ever. It won't work with you anyways because the IISC-server I'm running my "website" on is private and just for testing. source:

Downloader.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Downloader {
    public static void DownloadFile(String Indir,String Outdir,String Inname,String Outname) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        InputStream Input = new URL(Indir+"/"+Inname).openStream();
        if(new File(Outdir+"/"+Outname).exists()){
            new File(Outdir+"/"+Outname).delete();
        }
        File f = new File(Outdir);
        f.mkdirs();
        OutputStream Output = new FileOutputStream(Outdir+"/"+Outname);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(Input);
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            byte[] bytes = scan.nextLine().getBytes();
            Output.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
        Input.close();
        Output.close();
    }
}
```

Launcher.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class Launcher{
    private static final String dir = "http://tv-w7:8000/";

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        new Launcher(args);
    }
    public Launcher(String[] args){
        if(args.length==1){if(args[0].equals("f")){
            try {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "game is getting cleaned, press OK to proseed");
                    DownloadNewVersion(false,false);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else{
            try {

                Download();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void Download() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        if(new File(System.getenv("APPDATA")+"/MS2-torsteinv/MS2-bin/no/torsteinv/MarsSettlement2/Client/Client.class").exists()){
            InputStream AVIS = new URL(dir+"MS2-dat/CD.txt").openStream();
            InputStream CVIS = new FileInputStream(System.getenv("APPDATA")+"/MS2-torsteinv/MS2-dat/CD.txt");

            Scanner CVS = new Scanner(CVIS);
            Scanner AVS = new Scanner(AVIS);

            String CV = CVS.nextLine();
            String AV = AVS.nextLine();

            CVIS.close();
            AVIS.close();

            if(!CV.equals(AV))DownloadNewVersion(true,true);
            else start();
        }else{
            DownloadNewVersion(true,false);
        }
    }
    private void DownloadNewVersion(boolean promt,boolean N) throws IOException {
        if(promt && N)if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"A new verson is avalible. Download?")==1);
        InputStream OS = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -classpath "+System.getenv("APPDATA")+"\\MS2-torsteinv").getInputStream();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(OS);
        while(s.hasNext())System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new URL(dir+"MS2-register.txt").openStream());
        String CL = "";
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            CL = scan.nextLine();
            Downloader.DownloadFile(dir+CL.split(":")[0],System.getenv("APPDATA")+"/MS2-torsteinv/"+CL.split(":")[0],CL.split(":")[1],CL.split(":")[1]);
        }
        start();
    }
    private void start(){

        try {
            InputStream OS = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java ",System.getenv("APPDATA")+"\\MS2-torsteinv\\MS2-bin\\no\\torsteinv\\MarsSettlement2\\Client\\Client.class"}).getErrorStream();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(OS);
            while(s.hasNext())System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

i finaly got it to promt an error out:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file Client
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: Try writing the strings you're passing to `Runtime.exec()` to stdout, then copy/pasting them into a command line window to see if they're okay.

Comment: [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) is designed for auto-update amongst many other things.  Why not use a working solution?

Comment: what is JWS? and i dont use a working soulutsion i fight till i figure it out.as pathretic as it may sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because you treat a binary stream as if it contained characters encoded with your platform default encoding:

```
byte[] bytes = scan.nextLine().getBytes();
```

This considers that the input stream contains lines of text, transforms the bytes to characters (decoding: can be lossy, because all sequences of bytes don't represent valid characters), and then transforms the characters to bytes. And it also forgets to write the newline separators that could be in the binary stream.

Learn how to read and write binary data in [the Java IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html).

Side note: your code is hard to read because it doesn't respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: but it downloads just fine and all the files are just as thwey should be ie. no coruption. the problem was that when the start() method is ran it just stops and dosent run the program

Comment: btw i know that my code is hard to read. but i leart it all by my self so it probly conflicts with the standard naming laws.

Answer (score 0):

The end of your exec call has "Client.class". Should that be just "Client"?

Try this:

```
InputStream OS = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java", "-classpath", System.getenv("APPDATA")+"\\MS2-torsteinv\\MS2-bin\\no\\torsteinv\\MarsSettlement2\\Client", "Client"}).getErrorStream();
```

Comment: i tried but i still dosent work. the path and file exist and you probably saw that i set classpath so as always, java is being gay

Comment: @TorsteinVik I resent both of the implications of "java is being gay". The code in your question only sets the `-classpath` parameter in the `Download` method, where it doesn't say what class to execute. In `start`, where you say your code fails, you don't do that.

Comment: i got it to promt an error. its to long for the comment so i edited it into my question